# Add offset to UIInterpolatingMotionEffect

Tags: ios, ios7

I use code below to move an image in screen using parallax effect:

```
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalMotionEffect =
            [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
                    initWithKeyPath:@"center.y"
                               type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
    verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-20);
    verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(20);
```

But the value is -20 while device is level facing up, I need it to be 0 when device is facing up, how can I add of **offset** to value of **UIInterpolatingMotionEffect**?